# When to use "we are meant to be"?

Tags: meaning

I am Korean living in Seoul. I wanted to look up an expression which I can interpret 인연, Korean word describes the relationship meant to be. This expression is often used by men for pick up lines even at first sight. My question is "we are meant to be" can be used in the situation? Or is it only for long term relationship?

Comment: Phrases like "we were meant to be" or "we were destined to be together" are likely to be received as *very* cheesy, *especially* upon first meeting.  But this probably reflects a *cultural* difference, rather than a *linguistic* one.

Comment: Thank you Dan. "This is not a coincidence"-> is this better to use for the first meeting? I am working as a tour guide and working on my tour script ^^

Comment: It's better insofar as it's not as hackneyed (clichéd), but the problem isn't the wording so much as the underlying *sentiment*. That is, there isn't really a way to word it (in contemporary Western culture) that *wouldn't* come across as cheesy: no matter *how* you say it, it will come across as insincere and a bit ridiculous (because no one will believe that *you believe* you two were fated to meet, essentially because *our culture* doesn't credit that concept). That said.... I'm really interested in how your "tour script" relates to pickup lines!

Answer (score 2):

The expression "we were meant to be" as a pickup line is considered, as @DanBron says, "cheesy" in American culture.

***Two Perspectives on Romantic Love***

Permit me, if you would, to get a little philosophical for a moment. There are at least two general ways of looking at romantic love. One way is from the perspective of kismet, a word from Semitic roots which bespeaks fate, good fortune, or even God's will for two "star-crossed" lovers. In other words, fate/fortune/God meant for two people to come together in a lasting relationship--at least "until death do [them] part" (a common phrase in Western wedding vows, with the word *you* in place of the word *them*).

From this perspective, the exchange of vows publicly in a wedding ceremony (whether in a church, synagogue, or a mosque, or on a beach, in the office of a justice of the peace or in a room in city hall) only makes sense. The vows are a profound way (at least they should be) of officially and in the presence of God and witnesses sealing the relationship of "one husband and one wife for life."

Another way of looking at romantic love is from a more animalistic perspective. Guy meets girl. Guy and girl feel a strong attraction to one another. They "fall in love," fall into bed with one another, and do what comes natural. If they turn out to be somewhat compatible as a couple, they might decide to live together without the cultural sanction which accompanies a "wedding license." If the relationship doesn't work out, they may look at the failure as a "no harm, no foul" sort of hook-up, and simply call it quits--or perhaps become "friends with benefits," a euphemism for sex without commitment.

***"Made For" versus "Meant For"***

Of the two perspectives, the former is closer to the "meant to be" sort of romantic relationship. Instead of looking at the relationship through the spectacles of "we were *made for* each other," the former perspective (i.e., we were *meant for* each other) looks at the inevitability of the relationship--again, according to a predetermined fate, fortune, or divine matchup.

On a personal note, I identify more strongly with the "meant to be" perspective on love and marriage. Over 42 years ago in 1972, I met my wife in New York City at a Baptist church. She who was born in a predominantly Muslim country and had immigrated to America about four years before we met! Neither of us were Baptists. In fact, we came from the same (but much smaller) religious tradition, she in her country and I in mine. Since we did identify with the Baptists' doctrinal perspective, however, we found a church "home" there in Midtown Manhattan, and we were married in that church.

***Compatibility As the Best Predictor of "Meant To Be"***

I won't catalog the number of factors which brought us together and have kept us together for the last 40+ years, but I will suggest that our basic *compatibility* in the important areas of life (e.g., religion, values, family ties, and more) has been more influential in keeping our relationship alive and well than mere romantic love. Knowing that our marriage is a strong three-fold cord has made all the difference to us. (I'll leave you to determine who or what the third cord is!)

Answer (score 1):

If it is for your tour script as a tour guide may I recommend: happy [synchronicity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synchronicity); wonderful synchronicity--- " our meeting today in this tour is a wonderful synchronicity."

Synchronicity is the occurrence of two or more events that appear to be meaningfully related but not causally related. Synchronicity holds that such events are "meaningful coincidences". The concept of synchronicity was first defined by Carl Jung, a Swiss psychiatrist, in the 1920s.During his career, Jung furnished several slightly different definitions of it.

Jung variously defined synchronicity as an "acausal connecting (togetherness) principle," "meaningful coincidence," and "acausal parallelism." He introduced the concept as early as the 1920s but gave a full statement of it only in 1951 in an Eranos lecture.

In 1952, he published a paper "Synchronizität als ein Prinzip akausaler Zusammenhänge" (Synchronicity – An Acausal Connecting Principle) in a volume which also contained a related study by the Nobel laureate physicist Wolfgang Pauli.

Synchronicity implies that, just as events may be connected by causality, they may also be connected by meaning. Events connected by meaning need not have an explanation in terms of causality; this contradicts the Axiom of Causality in specific cases but does not contradict causality generally.

In his book Synchronicity: An Acausal Connecting Principle, Jung wrote:

How are we to recognize acausal combinations of events, since it is obviously impossible to examine all chance happenings for their causality? The answer to this is that acausal events may be expected most readily where, on closer reflection, a causal connection appears to be inconceivable.

Answer (score 0):

People do say "Maybe we are meant to be.", but not as a pickup line.  This line comes later when it seems you are getting on well together.

Simple meaning is "Maybe it is our destiny to be together."

However, we almost never say "we are meant to be".  The "maybe" almost always comes first.

Answer (score 0):

To me the sentence “we are meant to be together,simply showing a strong relationship between two people,to the extent they felt nothing can separate them...

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. Please consider editing your answer for clarity, particularly adding punctuation to indicate where the quote ends.